# Is there a better way to return a .json array for ajax in php?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a huge array of data in json format such as the shortened example below. And the only way to have the desired result was to encode and then decode, which seems quite absurd to me. 
I can't find myself a better way to code this, i hope you can help me out

```
$exDummy= '[{"ID":"149467","date":"2018-03-23","name":"Bill", },
{{"ID":"149445","date":"2018-03-25","name":"Joe", },
{{"ID":"168841","date":"2018-04-05","name":"Lily", }]';

// This is how i actually solved it. But i dont think its the proper way.
$exDummy = json_decode($exDummy);
return JwtCheckHeader::json($exDummy);
```

So im basically asking if there is a direct way to return this without this workaround.

I've tried these solutions which should return json but none worked. I'm looking for something similar to the following

```
return JwtCheckHeader::json($exDummy);
echo json_encode($exDummy);
echo $exDummy;
return $exDummy;
```

(return type was set in the ajax call)
Edited for clarification

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exactly is your problem? Why do you say your solution doesn't work?

Comment: If you get json data as a string, then using `json_decode()` isn't "absurd", it's what you _should_ use. Also, if you want to convert a PHP array to json, `json_encode()` is also the correct way. Not sure what the actual issue is here or what kind of solution you're hoping for?

Comment: The weird thing here is that the string is already in json format, or should.
I was expecting something like the examples mentioned above. 
I see this as php is forcing you to do something like :
translate this german text to spanish and then translate this spanish text to german because i can't understand it otherwise.

Comment: @Dharman my solution works (in the comment says "This is how i actually solved it..." ), but seems like inefficient or redundant. Maybe i might be unaware of something i dont know. So im just looking for a better way or some more information on why is this the only way to do this